# Can you call Slow Cheetah from the command line?

Tags: msbuild, slowcheetah

Can you call Slow Cheetah from the command line? I am looking to add a post build event to transform my config file for a variety of different environments.

Cheers
Dee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an issue with

```
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"
```

Changing that to

```
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets"
```

Allows it to run more dynamically without having to ever change the version.

Answer (score 7):

Step 1) Create a build file Transform.msbuild

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="TransformConfiguration" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"
             AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>

    <Target Name="TransformConfiguration">
    <TransformXml Source="$(sourceConfig)"
                  Transform="$(valuesConfig)"
                  Destination="$(outputConfig)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Step 2) Call MsBuild

```
msbuild Transform.msbuild /p:sourceConfig="app.config" /p:valuesConfig="App.Production.config" /p:outputConfig="AppName.config"
```

Comment: Just to confirm, this solution has no need for Slow Cheetah to be installed. If it could be edited to include Joe Martinez's modification it would be perfect.