# Using MSBuild to transform web.config

Tags: asp.net, web.config-transform

**EDITED for clarity (and updated my knowledge of problem)**
I've been working this a few days and can't seem to get it working. 
We utilize a build server which has Windows SDK 7.1 installed to run MSbuild (no visual studios). We run numerous  MSBuild project files to build different applications without problem. My application’s MSBuild worked fine until I added Web.Config transformation. Now it simply copies the various web.config’s (.debug.config, .release.config) rather than actually performing the transformation.

Our build command is

> msbuild projectfile.proj /p:label=sourceTree_Label /fl

Inside the projectfile.proj is an msbuild task

```
<Target Name="ProjectName" DependsOnTargets="otherProject">     
<PropertyGroup>
<ReleasePublishArgs>Configuration=Release;OutputPath=$(ReleaseOutputDir)\$(ProjectNameReleaseAssemblyName)_$(Major)_$(Minor)_$(Build)_$(Revision);</ReleasePublishArgs>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <!-- Release Build Section -->
        <Message Text="Creating Project for Release..." />

        <MSBuild
            Projects="$(ProjectBaseDir)\$(ProjectFile)"
            Targets="Clean"
            Properties="Configuration=Release" />
        <MSBuild
            Projects="$(ProjectBaseDir)\$(ProjectFile)"
            Targets="Rebuild"
            Properties="$(ReleasePublishArgs)" />
    </Target>
```

From what I have read MSBuild should simply handle the transform. However, it isn’t working for me. So do I need to modify the .csproj file, projectfile.proj, or the initial MSBuild command (or am I missing some sort of library on the machine that is required)?

*Note: Due to legal & IT restrictions I can not import 3rd party systems (SlowCheetah) into our corporate baseline*

Comment: **MSBuild** things i tried:
  'MSBuild msbuild.script DeployOnBuild=True /p:label...' 
  'MSBuild msbuild.script /p:Configuration=Release /p:TransformConfigFiles=true /p:label...' 
   'MSBuild msbuild.script /p:Configuration=Release /t:TransformWebConfig /p:label...'         **(Fails)**
   
**Modify .csproj** with
     1) '<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(PublishProfileName)' == '' And '$(WebPublishProfileFile)' == ''">
 <TransformXml 
  Source="Web.config" 
  Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" 
  Destination="Web.config" />
  </Target>'

Comment: **Modify .csproj** with
'<Target Name="TransformConfig" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(TransformConfig)'=='true'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <DeleteAfterBuild Include="$(OutDir)Web.*.config" />
      <DeleteAfterBuild Include="$(OutDir)ConnStrings.*.config" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="$(FileName)" Destination="$(OutDir)Web.config" />
    <TransformXml Source="ConnStrings.config" Transform="ConnStrings.$(Configuration).config" Destination="$(OutDir)ConnStrings.config" />
    <Delete Files="@(DeleteAfterBuild)" />
  </Target>'

Comment: I'm guessing slow cheetah is installed via nuget? And you have msbuild on your build server because no TFS? Also, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404266/can-you-call-slow-cheetah-from-the-command-line

Comment: No, SlowCheetah is not installed. We do have MsBuild installed on the build server. As I said the MSBuild works fine on our project when we had just a base Web.Config. It's only the transform that is new and not working via MSBuild.

Comment: I'm used to being in a TFS environment using web deploy (and slow cheetah via nuget). However, I *believe* that without publishing and just building you will need to use slow cheetah (it's free). If you have setup a publish profile you should be able to pass /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<Profile Name> to msbuild. Also, slow Cheetah will let you right click on your web.<cfg>.config and preview it.

Comment: SlowCheetah is not an option, due to licensing and IT restrictions. 
All I'm looking for is a way to execute the Web.Config transform via MSBuild, that Visual Studios already does automatically.

Comment: Then you have to do a publish after the build if those are your restrictions. Slow cheetah has been around a while and was created by a guy on the tfs team who also has written some popular books on tfs. Perhaps you can persuade yoir IT people. You can check this out too but slow cheetah is your best option outside of a publish: https://lostechies.com/erichexter/2013/01/20/asp-net-web-config-transform-console-utility-released-on-nuget/

Comment: Could you provide any guidance on how to perform the Publish? I tried msbuild.../t:Clean;Rebuild;Publish, but that results in a '_DeploymentUnpublishable Skipping unpublishable project' with no indication why it is unpublishable. Is there some additional step or parameter I am missing?

Comment: Did yiu try the parameters i mentioned above? I'm actually on vacation for the rest of the week so...Also you put them inside of your csproj file.